# How to remove bad objects from my reponse.data before setting state

Tags: reactjs

It is possible to remove objects from the response.data before setting the state?

I want to remove any objects where `postContent: ""` or `imgUrl: ""`. It doesn't look good when the objects are displaying with no image && content.

Json:
https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json

How I'm storing the data:

```
  private getProfiles() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +
        "https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          profiles: response.data
        });
      })
      // Error catching
      .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

Comment: @BennKingy Keep in mind I think you want a logical `or` rather than `and` according to your question.

Comment: @silencedogood From the question: `I want to remove any objects where postContent: "" or imgUrl: ""` To me that means if either one is empty then throw it out.

Comment: @HMR exactly... So you don't want `and` because that means both conditions would have to be met. Correct?

Comment: @silencedogood You made me doubt there but: `response.data.filter(d=>d.postContent&&d.imgUrl)` is correct. Both have to contain something to be included.

Comment: @HMR so what happens when he has a record where `postContent: ''` and `imgURL: 'hasValue'` ?? This would mean the condition wouldn't be met and an undesirable record would be included in his state.

Comment: @silencedogood try it in a console: `console.log(
Boolean(''&&''),
Boolean('x'&&''),
Boolean(''&&'x'),
Boolean('x'&&'x'),
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array method to remove unwanted items.

```js
private getProfiles() {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +
      "https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json"
    )
    .then(response => {

      this.setState({
        profiles: response.data.filter(item => item.postContent && item.imgUrl)
      });
    })
    // Error catching
    .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors, isLoading: false }));
}
```

Comment: That would cause profiles to have a lot of undefined elements. Maybe use filter instead?

Comment: @HMR you are right, filter is better here. I updated answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the object item in the array before setting state:

```
.then(response => {
    var cleanData = response.data.filter(item => {
        return (item.postContent && item.imgUrl)
    });

    this.setState({
      profiles: cleanData
    });
  })
```

Comment: This returns the item if the postContent is empty, and also imgUrl must be item.imgUrl.

Comment: Should use `!==` or you'll get linter errors (never use type coercion unless you have no choice).

Comment: your statement must be item.postContent !== "" &&  item.imgUrl !== "",
or better to use item.postContent && item.imgUrl  as in my answer

Comment: @silencedogood Not quite there yet :-), now it includes all items where either one of the required strings is empty. If both are set then item is filtered out. Filter callback has to return true or false, you could use: `return Boolean(item.postContent&&item.imgUrl)` meaning both cannot be empty.

Comment: @HMR lol thx my brains gotten all twisted around on this one. However, I just ran a test seems to have confirmed my stance on the `and` vs. `or` I just don't see where you're coming from on that...

Comment: @HMR Perhaps this [codepen](https://codepen.io/silencedogood/pen/bGGVyoP?editors=1111) is an incorrect application, but this is why I was thinking `or` is correct.

Comment: @silencedogood The filter function needs to return false if **either** a or b is ''. If you run the following in the console you see that `a&&b` is only returning true where both a and b are not empty: `console.log( Boolean(''&&''), Boolean('x'&&''), Boolean(''&&'x'), Boolean('x'&&'x'), )`

Comment: @HMR dang thanks for your patience not sure why my brain is in dyslexic mode right now; I was looking at it backwards.